# Flex 3: write multiple characters with a single button (like cellphone keypad where 3 can also be used for D, E, F)

Tags: apache-flex, flex3, implementation, keypad

I'm implementing a small keypad where the click on a button will add the respective character to a text input. However, some keys should be used to insert more than on character, like a cellphone keypad where the button "3" can also be used to insert "D", "E" or F.
Which would be the best approach to accomplish this? I'm not very experienced yet with Flex.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just implemented you a "start from". Hope this helps you ;)

http://pastie.org/3314957

[image]

Comment: A one more, you can configure repeate rate and autoRepeat flag form button. The user don't need to click all the time.